# Check cell in excel which should accept only text

Tags: vba, excel

If ((Asc(ActiveCell) > 65 And Asc(ActiveCell) < 95) Or (Asc(ActiveCell) > 97 And Asc(ActiveCell) < 122)) Then
        'If Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText(ActiveCell) Then
        'If ((Asc(ActiveCell) < 65 And Asc(ActiveCell)) > 90 Or (Asc(ActiveCell) < 97 And Asc(ActiveCell) > 122)) Then
          Else
           FnameTextOnly.Add ActiveCell.Address(False, False)
        End If
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
this is code is working properly when the value of cell e.g:12as,@#$%,1234
but if i enter data e.g:asd34 then it should not accept but its accepting because the name starts with text.

Comment: Please describe exactly what you want to test for, what's valid, what's not and why.

Comment: first name(fname) must contain only aplhabets if not i am priniting cell address which are having wrong data

Comment: So anything that's not comprised solely of A-Z/a-z is invalid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an If statement for ISTEXT (cell reference) to your routine. In this way, ISTEXT (asd34) = False. After qualifying true or false branch accordingly.

Comment: ISTEXT doesn't check for special characters

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to test the *ActiveCell*

```
Sub CellText()
    Dim CH As String, v As String
    v = ActiveCell.Text
    For i = 1 To Len(v)
        CH = Mid(v, i, 1)
        If CH Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
        Else
            MsgBox v & " is not valid"
            Exit Sub
        End If
    Next i
MsgBox v & " is valid"
End Sub
```

Comment: But this is ignore value e.g:hgh67. This is working properly for value e.g: 8789jhghj

Comment: @RajaniRampelli On my computer, any cell with non-letters gets the error message